# Google firestore rest API: How to create documents within a transaction

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, transactions

Using a transaction ref I can update multiple documents by creating an array/list of `Write` objects and then doing a `CommitRequest`.

However I can find no way of creating new documents within the transaction? `firestoreApi.projects.databases.documents.createDocument(...)` Doesn't provide have a `transaction` parameter. `Write` seems to for updating documents and not creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

Creating documents from a transaction is definitely possible. You would first need to begin a new transaction using the `projects.databases.documents.beginTransaction` [endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/beginTransaction). After using the `beginTransaction` endpoint, you will receive a transaction ID that can be used with the `projects.databases.documents.commit` [endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/commit). This endpoint does use a `Write` object, but the `Write` object has a `currentDocument` property which is a [Precondition type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/Precondition). The Precondition object in turn has a property called `exists`, which needs to be set to false so that it can be declared that a document does not exist.

> When it is set to true, the target document must exist. When it is set to false, the target document must not exist.

This allows a new document to be created from the transaction, and then the transaction is committed.